# How to redirect to a view from Custom Authorization filter Web Api

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponse, httpresponsemessage

I have a Custom Authorization Attribute for my web API. I want to show resource not found page if my API link is accessed directly from a browser.  Can this be done?

So far i have managed to encode resourse not found in the HttpResponse message. 
I tried to use string content and put html tags on it but its not working. Is  there any other way?

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
    {    
        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(): base()
        {    
        }    
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {   
            if (!(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User).Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                string message = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> Page Not Found </title></head><bod>";
                   message+= "< h2 style = 'text-align:center'> Sorry, Page Not Found </ h2 ></body></html> ";
                actionContext.Response.Content = new StringContent(message);  

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the content type on the response:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute() : base()
    {
    }
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            string message =
                "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> Page Not Found </title></head><body><h2 style='text-align:center'> Sorry, Page Not Found </h2></body></html>";
            response.Content = new StringContent(message);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");

            actionContext.Response = response;
        }
    }
}
```